# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 128 into shape (64,64)

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I am extracting the face embedding of face images and then need to show it. For this purpose I am using below function:

```
def show_orignal_images(pixels):
    # Displaying Orignal Images
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 10, figsize=(11, 7), subplot_kw={'xticks':[], 'yticks':[]})
    for p, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
        ax.imshow(np.array(pixels)[p].reshape(64, 64), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Below is how I am extracting the embedding and plotting it:

```
for (z, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}, name {}".format(z + 1, len(imagePaths), imagePath))

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    imageBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0), swapRB=False, crop=False)

    detector.setInput(imageBlob)
    detections = detector.forward()

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > 0.5:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            (fH, fW) = face.shape[:2]

            faceBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0 / 255, (96, 96), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)

            embedder.setInput(faceBlob)
            vec = embedder.forward()
            knownNames.append(name)
            knownEmbeddings.append(vec.flatten())


targets = knownNames
pixels = knownEmbeddings

show_orignal_images(pixels)
```

but its giving me an error :

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 128 into shape (64,64)
```

How can I resolve it. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cannot reshape `128` into `(64,64)`. Because `64x64=4096`. But you can reshape the data into a shape `(i,j) with i*j=128`, for example `(2,64)`, or `(8, 16)`

Comment: Did you mean I should update `def show_orignal_images(pixels):` and do `ax.imshow(np.array(pixels)[p].reshape(2, 64), cmap='gray')` ?

Comment: This would give you an image with a 2x64 resolution

Comment: You are right, its showing with very low resolution. How can I change the resolution to visulalize it good

Comment: I do not know this, the input `pixels` should contain more data points

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I delete some third dimension, reshape into 64,64 and reshape to 1d array for my function.

```
def show_orignal_single_image(pixels):
    #function for show original image
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.subplots()
    f = ax.imshow(np.array(pixels).reshape(64,64), cmap='gray')
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()

img = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Final_Project_Data/person_with_mask.png")
width, height = img.size

#resize
img = img.resize((64,64))
width, height = img.size

#convert to grayscale
img = img.convert('LA')

numpy_image = np.asarray(img)

#Rehape to 64*64
numpy_image = numpy_image[:,:,0]
#Reshape to 4096
numpy_image = numpy_image.reshape(-1)


#test show_orignal_single_image
show_orignal_single_image(numpy_image)
```